# Load large csv files to Hive through Ambari

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, ambari

I am trying to load large csv files (each of ~4G) to Hive through Ambari.
The CREATE TABLE - LOAD DATA process below works fine for smaller csv files but not for such big ones. It keeps returning the server error "failed to fetch table information".

The codes I am currently using are:

`CREATE TABLE my_table(
  id int, 
  text string )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;`

and

`LOAD DATA INPATH 'mypath/INPUT.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE my_table;`

Is there a better way to upload large csv files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can `hdfs dfs -put` the files into the `hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse` location

Comment: Hi cricket_007, thanks for your response. But now I already have my files up on the hdfs, I am struggling on how to load the tables into Hive tables.

Comment: If the files are already in HDFS, then `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ... LOCATION 'hdfs:///your_hdfs_path'`

Comment: My understanding this command only creates a table frame, which does not contains any datalines other than the headers. How do I put data into the External Table then? Thanks.

Comment: An external table in only metadata over actual files in storage. Any data that is setup by your table properties such as `row format delimited fields terminated by` or `stored as` gets applied to all existing files in that location... The alternative would be to first create a non-external table, then use `LOAD DATA` commands like you've already done. Either way, the size of the file shouldn't matter because you are not actually "moving" any data around. The solution here, in my opinion is to not use a web UI such as Ambari, and go use Beeline, where you could get a better error message

Answer (score 0):

Can you please create the table by not mentioning the file format (text).

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
  id int, 
  text string )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

And, then, can you please upload the file in a different location where the table has been created. Then can you please try to use the load data inpath query?

Comment: Hi Tanvir, I am still experiencing the same " Failed to fetch table information" Error after loading data inpath query.

Answer (score 0):

First create table then run `show create table my_table;`

In this you see structure of table where `hdfs location` is also mentioned for that table.
on that hdfs path put files which you want to load in table.